concatenar SELECT * FROM y SHOW STATUS
Estoy creando un proyecto que se conecta con una base de datos que solo tiene conexiones limitadas. Cuando mi API es llamada genera una conexión y si la ejecuto por arriba del limite, hace que la se congele todo en mi servidor online.
Noté que puedo contar las conexiones usando SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name = Threads_connected
y así creé una sentencia que cuenta las conexiones y al final yo cancelo las llamadas cuando llegue a un limite de 20.
Hasta aquí todo bien, pero tengo dos paginas que hacen llamados y mandar a llamar la sentencia anterior junto con otra me crearía el doble conexiones y eso es lo que no quiero.
Entonces quisiera saber si hay forma de concatenar un SELECT * FROM TABLE y el SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name = THreads connected en una sola sentencia para que me dé tanto los datos que quiero de mi tabla como las conexiones.

Pero por qué haces una conexión por cada sentencia?? No sería mejor reutilizar la conexión y cerrarla al acabar de montar todo??

y si llaman a tu api al mismo tiempo una cantidad mayor a la cantidad de conexiones permitidas?? aca suena a que tenes otro problema...

Te recomiendo usar un pool de conexiones
